# power steering fluid leak o2 accord ex 4cyl vtec

Tags: honda

02 accord ex 4cyl vtec leaking power steering fluid when car is running or not as long as i keep putting fluid in it runs great seems to be leaking where it goes int steering wheel could it be a o ring

Comment: Not much we can do in helping you find the leak, get it fixed before it damages the ps pump.

Comment: Your leak could be a) on a pressure side which, IMO would 1) empty your pump quickly when engine is running and 2) spray all over the place or b) on a low pressure side which would likely leak much more slowly.